# How to properly use orderby to modify default WordPress query

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to modify the default WordPress to change how the posts are ordered on the homepage. I am unable to figure out how to use `orderby` parameter. This is what I am using:

```php
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'my_custom_query' );

function my_custom_query( $query ) {

    if( $query->is_main_query() && ! is_admin() && $query->is_home() ) {
        $query->set( 'orderby', 'post_title');
        $query->set( 'order' ,'ASC');   
        $query->set( 'posts_per_page', '3' );
    }
}
```

Only the `posts_per_page` parameter works and `orderby` does not change. I have tried using `orderby date, rand, title`, etc.

Comment: Try orderby title instead of post_title

Comment: tried title it didn't work either.

Comment: curious why you want to change the default query... looks like you want to do some custom logic on home page? If so, just write a custom arg `get_posts` and output whatever you want on that template. No need to modify the main query.